# C++ shared_ptr and mutex

Tags: c++, mutex, shared-ptr

I'm new to C++ and I have to following scenario:

main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

int main() {
    Bar bar{};
    auto bar_ptr = std::make_shared<Bar>(bar);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Foo foo{bar_ptr};
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want 10 Instances of Class Foo to share 1 Instance of Class Bar. Each Instance of Class Foo will run in a separate Thread. I want the shared Instance of Class Bar only to be accessed by one Instance of Foo at a time. That's why I wanted to add a std::mutex to Foo. This seems to conflict with std::mutex not being copyable/moveable. What is the correct way to use a mutex with a shared_ptr?

Foo.h

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include "Bar.h"

class Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr;

public:
    explicit Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr){
        this->bar_ptr = std::move(bar_ptr);
    }
};
```

Bar.h

```
#include <mutex>

class Bar {
    std::mutex mutex{};

};
```

Comment: `Bar bar{}; auto bar_ptr = std::make_shared<Bar>(bar);` This doesn't work, since `Bar` does not provide a copy constructor. Simply stick with the object stored in the shared pointer and if you absolutely need access to the object via the identifier `bar`, create, make it a reference: `Bar& bar = *bar_ptr;`

Comment: In addition to the answer you've gotten, I suggest that you make the `mutex` `mutable` and use the member initializer list. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Y47cG8Wha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::mutex` is a move-only type, so you can't copy it.

In your main function you are creating a `Bar`, and then trying to create a `std::shared_ptr` by copying that instance of `Bar`.

Instead, just use `std::make_shared<Bar>()` to create a `shared_ptr` to a bar with the default constructor.

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

int main() {
    auto bar_ptr = std::make_shared<Bar>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Foo foo{bar_ptr};
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To clarify, the arguments passed to `make_shared` are forwarded to the constructor of the class. If you pass a `Bar&` it will try to use the copy constructor.

If you pass nothing it will use the default constructor.

If `Bar`s constructor takes arguments in your real use-case, pass the arguments to `make_shared`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <mutex>

class Bar {
    public:
    Bar(int i) : value(i) {}
    private:
    std::mutex mutex{};
    int value;
};

class Foo {
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_ptr;

public:
    // Use the initializer list when possible
    // Otherwise we first default-construct then assign
    explicit Foo(std::shared_ptr<Bar> ptr) : bar_ptr(std::move(ptr)) {}
};

int main() {
    auto bar_ptr = std::make_shared<Bar>(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Foo foo{bar_ptr};
    }

    return 0;
}
```